# Why don't temporary return types of rvalue functors cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, temporaries

I'm new to rvalues and lvalues so please forgive me.

Say I have the following code:

```
int&& temp() { return 5400; }

int x = temp();
```

This code compiles just fine with MSVC. When I print out x, it prints 5400. Shouldn't this not be possible, since `temp()` returns a reference to a destroyed object?

Comment: What must undefined behaviour look like, that you expect to identify it so easily?

Comment: I added `cout << x << "\n";`.  Compiled, I got `5400` output.  Compiled again with `-O3` and got `1` output.  The joys of **undefined behavior**.  If you are unlucky, it can appear to work.  If you are lucky, it will crash.

Comment: Compiler should warn about this, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VafuY4DPOngmOD2Q.  If MSVC doesn't then, depending on the warning level you're using, Microsoft dropped the ball.  And you should be returning `42` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does cause undefined behavior because you are returning and accessing a reference to an object that is destroyed when the function returns, specifically a temporary `int` object materialized from the `5400` prvalue in the `return` statement to bind the reference in the return value to. Whether the return type is a (`const`) lvalue reference or a rvalue reference does not matter at all.

Undefined behavior means that there are *no guarantees* on the behavior of the program. It seemingly working is one possible outcome when no guarantees are given, but so is any other outcome as well, and none can be relied upon.

Comment: Wait, why would this be UB? You can't initialize an `int` with a prvalue?

Comment: @NathanPierson the return value is initialized and the locals are destroyed.  That leaves the returned reference dangling.